# Example of a PDE model with nonlinear Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: pde, boundary-conditions, parabolic-pde

Is there any application for PDEs with nonlinear Dirichlet boundary conditions? That is, I am looking for an example of a partial differential equation for a state $u$ posed on a domain $\Omega$ with $g(u|_{\Gamma})=0$, where $\Gamma$ is the boundary of $\Omega$ and $g\in L^2(\Gamma)\to L^2(\Gamma)$ is a nonlinear function.

Note that I am looking for pure Dirichlet conditions. I am aware of the Stefan-Boltzmann boundary conditions for heat conduction, but they are Robin-type boundary conditions.

**EDIT:**

As @Wolfgang Bangerth has pointed out in his answer, there is no sense in assigning boundary values via a nonlinear $g\in L^2(\Gamma)\to L^2(\Gamma)$.

What if the boundary values are fixed via a function $G \in \bigl ( L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Gamma) \bigr)$? Something like $u|_\Gamma(x)=g(x)\|u\|$. Has anyone come across such an example.

I am insisting so much on this point, because I was investigating the incorporation of boundary conditions of a PDE by means of multipliers. When, instead of resolving the BCs in the ansatz space, looking at a PDE of the Form
$ F(u)=0 \text{ in } (H^1(\Omega))',$
completed by $G(u)=0$, where $G:H^1(\Omega) \to H^{1/2}(\Gamma)$ assigns the Dirichlet conditions, I found it interesting to think of what may happen with a nonlinear $G$.

**EDIT 2:**

When considering unsteady processes, there can be a unique solution, even if the boundary data $g(u)=0$ allows for multiple values. An example is the Stefan problem formulated for the enthalpy $u$ as considered e.g. by [Nochetto et al.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2938664?origin=JSTOR-pdf).

There, the boundary condition is given in terms of $\theta(u)=0$ on $\Gamma$, where $\theta$ is a monotone Lipshitz-continuous scalar function, with - in particular - $\theta(s)=0$ for $s\in(0,1)$.

Thus, there is no way to reduce the nonlinear Dirichlet to a linear assignment, as $\theta$ is not injective in the region of interest.

**EDIT 3:**

Another source of nonlinear boundary conditions are free surface problems, where the boundary itself depends on the solution. See, for example, this [ArXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1418) of a paper by Sprittles & Shikhmurzaev.

Again, this is in line with @Wolfgang Bangerth's answer, as the BCs for free surface problems involve spatial derivatives and, thus, are nonlocal. In his book *[Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations with Applications](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:1087.35002&format=complete)* (p. 155), the author Roubicek provides an example for a wetting problem of flow in porous media. Apart from the formulation as a partial differential variational inequality it includes the boundary condition
$$
u\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0,
$$
on nonpermeable interfaces.

Comment: Are you interested when g couples mutliple points on the boundary together, or when g simply applies a non-linear constraint at each point individually?

Comment: It should be a pointwise constraint (I have edited the question accordingly). But a coupling of the boundarie points, e.g. via an integral relation, might be also ok.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This makes no sense. Let us assume that $g(z)=0$ has exactly one solution $z=z^\ast$, then your boundary condition $g(u|_\Gamma)=0$ is equivalent to $u|_\Gamma=z^\ast$, i.e., a linear Dirichlet condition.

On the other hand, if there are multiple solutions of $g(z)=0$, then you are saying that the value $u|_\Gamma$ could have multiple values, but this does not lead to a unique solution of the equation and so it makes no sense.

In a similar vein, it makes no sense to have nonlinear Neumann boundary conditions. The only thing that does make sense is to have nonlinear Robin-type conditions, $(\partial u/\partial n+g(u))|_\Gamma = 0$. A typical case is the Planck radiation condition $(D\partial u/\partial n+\gamma u^4)|_\Gamma = 0$.

Comment: I can think of some sense. Namely, the law that is imposed at the boundary is nonlinear. I agree, that well-posedness requires the existence of an implicit function, such that locally one has $g(u)=0 \Leftrightarrow u=z^*$ . In practise, however, this $z^*$ may be accessible only pointwise via nonlinear solves, so that the actual implementation bases on nonlinear boundary conditions. This is hypothetic, but that is my question.

Comment: Well, but that doesn't make any sense. If you have a boundary condition $g(u,x)=0$, then for every $x$ you have a Dirichlet condition of the form $u(x)|_\Gamma=z^\ast(x)$ -- i.e., a linear Dirichlet boundary condition. Maybe it's been computed by a nonlinear solver, but the *equation* is linear: it can be solved in one shot, without having to iterate out the equation.

Comment: I see your point. If $u|_\Gamma$ is defined by external data, it is in fact a linear assignment. Conversely, a nonlinear relation might appear if $u|_\Gamma$ depends on internal states. I.e. when the side condition of the PDE is given via $g(u)=0$ where $g$ maps from the state space onto* the boundary. *onto has to be understood wrt. to the setting. In a weak formulation this will be into a dual of the space of traces.

Comment: Right. Such as the Robin condition I mentioned where the normal derivative clearly involves information from the interior.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I do not understand your argument for the Neumann case. It clearly involves information from the interior, and it could be nonlinear.

Comment: What I meant is that a boundary condition of the form $h(\partial u/\partial n)=0$ is a *linear* boundary condition, even if $h$ is nonlinear.

Comment: Yes, I see. Note that a transmission condition can also be nonlinear, in addition to a Robin condition.

Comment: How about non-local boundary conditions of the form $\int_\Omega u(x) d\Omega = p(x,u(x))|_\Gamma$, where $p$ could be a non-linear function of $u$? An example can be found here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42586/form-of-nonlinear-diffusion-equation. Do these also map to the form $u|_\Gamma = z^*$?