# Form of nonlinear diffusion equation

Tags: pde, parabolic-pde, diffusion, pdepe

Consider the following nonlinear diffusion problem,

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = x^{-2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2 u^4 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right), \quad 0 < x < 1
$$

We can notice that if $v = u^5/5$, we can simplify the diffusion term to

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = x^{-2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2 \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right), \quad 0 < x < 1
$$

The time derivative can also be replaced recognizing that

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = u^{-4} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = \frac{u}{5v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}
$$

While the transformation eliminates the non-linearity in the diffusion term, we potentially face trouble evaluating the nonlinear mass matrix, say if the initial condition where $u = 0$.

*Q1: Is there a way out of this situation? Perhaps by solving for both $u_t$ and $v_t$ (or $\dot{v}$) in time?*

*Q2: Does the idea of performing the semi-discretization in terms of $v = u^5 / 5$ have merit?*

If possible I'd like to use the `pdepe` solver in MATLAB. The original form is compatible with `pdepe`, however I thought the solution may be more accurate if semi-discretized for $v$ instead.

**Edit (additional information)**

For a bit more context, this problem appears as Example A on pg. 15 in the report:

> Bakker, M. (1977). Software for semi-discretization of time-dependent partial differential equations in one space variable:(preprint). Stichting Mathematisch Centrum. Numerieke Wiskunde, (52/77).

A PDF (3MB) can be downloaded [here](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/9016).

The full problem is to solve:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = x^{-2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(x^2 u^4 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right), \quad 0 < x < 1
$$

given the boundary conditions,

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0, \; x = 0\\
5 \int_0^1 x^2 u(x,t) dx + [u(1,t)]^5 = 1
$$

and initial condition

$$
u(x,0) = \begin{cases}0, \; 0 \leq x < 1\\
0, \; x = 1 \end{cases}
$$

In the original report the author chose to semi-discretize the right-hand side (or flux term) as a function of $v = u^5/5$. With `pdepe` it is not possible to do so, as the gradient $\frac{\partial v }{ \partial x}$ would only be available if $v(x,t)$ was solved for as a second PDE. (Implementing the integral is a second problem...)

Here is what the solution looks like, obtained with linear finite elements on an equidistant mesh with 80 elements:

[image: Solution of nonlinear diffusion problem]

The sharp penetrating front in the solution presents quite a challenge for numerical schemes.

The steady-state solution can be obtained from the second boundary condition, by substituting $u(x,t) = u_\infty$, which results in the non-linear equation
$$
\frac{5}{3} u_\infty + u_\infty^5 = 1
$$
with solution $u_\infty \approx 0.565$.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the second boundary condition where an integral appears is also called an _integral_ or _nonlocal_ boundary condition.